# catching error json string from facebook api

Tags: facebook, json, api, debugging, parsing

i am trying to catch error messages, that are sent from the facebook api when trying to post to a wall.

here is the json string that gets returned.
{"error":{"message":"(#506) Duplicate status message","type":"OAuthException","code":506,"error_data":{"kError":1455006}}}

how would i parse this string using the JavaScriptSerializer, as if i try to use the word "error" in a class as my property, it will not allow it as its a keyword in c#. code is below.

```
Dim dbg As StreamReader = New StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream)
Dim jss = New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim fbdebug As fbDebuger = jss.Deserialize(Of fbDebuger)(dbg.ReadToEnd)
Response.Write(fbdebug.error)
```

Public Class fbDebuger
        Public Property error As String

```
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Keywords can be used by adding brackets around the variable name.